# Facebook SDK integration - using a view controller instead of the app delegate

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, uiapplicationdelegate

As the title suggests, I now find myself utilising the new Facebook SDK--available [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)-- within my iOS application.

I've followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) introduction outlined on the Facebook developer site, and everything works as it should--at least according to their implementation.

Their way of doing things means the user is presented with the choice to connect their account to the app after applicationDidFinishLaunching is called, via a series of methods and calls within the app delegate.

I would instead like to only force this upon the selection of a button within a view controller buried elsewhere in the app. That is, I don't want to deal with authorisation when applicationDidFinishLaunching is called--I want my own method in a view controller to force it. Also, I will be referencing the Facebook classes from a number of my own view controllers, if that makes any difference.

I've searched far and wide and have yet to come up with a fully explained solution (or anything at all, really) for dealing with this. If anyone has ideas about how to go about this, please let me know. StackOverflow is a last resort most of the time :)

Edit: As beryllium brought up below, I can simply take everything that is meant to be in the app delegate and slap it into each individual view controller. It works, but is this the best way to handle this unique situation or is there a better implementation to be had?

Thank you,

Relevant code below:

sampleAppDelegate.h

```
@interface sampleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,FBRequestDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBLoginDialogDelegate> {

Facebook *facebook;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;

@end
```

sampleAppDelegate.m

```
  @synthesize facebook;

      facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"102698856525645" andDelegate:self];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
            && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
            facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
            facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        }

        if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
            NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"offline_access", 
                                    @"publish_stream",
                                    nil];
            [facebook authorize:permissions];
            [permissions release];   
        } 
    }
    // For 4.2+ support
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
        return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
    }

    - (void)fbDidLogin {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];

    } 
/*methods required by Facebook SDK to handle issues with connectivity--all currently empty*/
```

viewController.h

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "sampleAppDelegate.h"

@class sampleAppDelegate;


@interface viewController : UIViewController <FBRequestDelegate> {
    Facebook *facebook;
        UnitedUpdatesAppDelegate *facebookSampleAppDelegate;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) sampleAppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
```

viewController.m

```
-(void) facebookPost {
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                   @"http://stackoverflow.com", @"link",
                                   @"Message name", @"name",
                                   @"Caption", @"caption",
                                   @"Description", @"description",
                                   @"Message",  @"message",
                                   nil];

    [sampleAppDelegate dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate: sampleAppDelegate];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to Cmd+X and Cmd+V to cut and insert code from appDelegate into your VC?

Comment: Beryllium, would that be the best way to go? It certainly works--I neglected to mention my previous attempt at that in the original post--but is it how such an implementation should be handled? This is my first usage of the Facebook API, obviously!, so my knowledge of their system is perhaps not as great as I might like. Thank you for the prompt!

Comment: I think code that work in one place can successfully work in another place as well. So, if you will transfer code without mistakes and will not miss something, then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this Facebook code shouldn't be part of any view controller. I prefer to create a Singleton class to handle the communication with Facebook. This Singleton conforms to a certain interface, making it more convenient to add other services like Twitter to the app (each service could be handled by a separate singleton conforming to the shared interface).

The interface could define methods like *-login:*, *-logout:*, *-postMessage:*, i.e. methods shared by most services.

The singleton might use delegates or blocks to handle web service responses in a similar way, e.g. in case of a delegate implementation some methods could be called *-service:didSucceedWithStatus:* or *-service:didFailWithError:* (where the *service* parameter would indicate the type of service or singleton instance that sends the delegate message).

I actually did write some code according to the above description and could post it here if you're interested.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, any and all help you could provide would be fantastic, especially as you have dealt with the troubles the Facebook SDK presents before. I certainly like your idea of keeping everything Facebook in one class and am curious to see how you managed it. I'm quite grateful for your assistance!

Comment: would you be able to post your singleton code? I'm stuck on this very thing right now. thank you

Comment: The code is kinda old and might be a little bit buggy, but it should give you the general idea on how to implement such a thing: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6487838/Facebook-Singleton.zip - I hope I can create an improved version in the future (the linked code was written like 1,5 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

If You are asking if is possible or even better to use delegate methods in other places than AppDelegate, the answer is YES.

My idea is to prepare a class containing all the stuff for FB and have a button than can trigger the login and/ or authentication.

Usually is enough to make your controller adopt the protocols FB classes need, and delegate it to answer to callback.

I tried a similar approach and it works fine.

Comment: Ingconti, might you guide me further in the right direction? Is there a blog post I've missed where this is explained? I'm stumbling on how to translate all of the app delegate methods to a class of its own. Would I just copy everything over that is meant to in the app delegate? Is it really THAT simple? :)